# Have tried every method on this site but whitespace below img still exists

Tags: css

I know this question has been asked many times but I feel like I have exhausted all solutions and don't know what else to do.

When I add an image, there is so much white space. This hasn't happened to any other image I've put on my page. I've tried adding "display: block" on both img & container tags, vertical-inline top/bottom etc., line-height: 0 to the container tag, float properties to img, you name it I've tried it, and NOTHING has worked.

What is interesting is that when I set the width: 200 px the image becomes tiny but the white space disappears. Any larger than that and I get teh white space. I obviously cannot use a teeny image for my website tho.  Please help as I am at my wit's end.

```
 <main>

    <section id="banner"> 
    <h1>The Pet Hospitals</h1>
    <h2>we know pets</h2>
    <img src="images/doggo2.png" alt="dog">
</section>


<section class="welcome">
    <h1>welcome!</h1>
    <img src="images/logo4.png" alt="logo">
      <div class="container">
         <div>
           <h2>First visit? Don't be skittish.</h2>
           <p>All new clients can enjoy a free first exam by mentioning 
this     
                   offer. We also provide discounted vaccination and 
treatment                              packages for puppies and kittens to 
start them on the right paw!
        </p>
                 </div>
         <div>
                   <h2>Boarding, Grooming & Doggie Daycare</h2>
           <p>We offer a full spectrum of boarding, grooming & doggie daycare services. Whether       
                   it's a day at the spa, a day of play, or a longer staycation, your pet is in good                           hands.</p>
             </div>
         <div>
                    <h2>Refill Prescriptions</h2>
        <p>You're busy, so we make refills easy. We also competitively price match all of                         your pet's medications. Request a refill via our Chat Now feature or give us a              call and we'll hop on it.</p>
                 </div>
     </div>
       </section>


<section class="wants">
     <img src="images/dogcat.png" alt="doggo">
          <div class="wantstext">
           <h2>They know what they want. We know what they need</h2>
           <p>Fur babies know how to give you the irresistible eyes when they                              want a treat, but they don’t always know how to tell you that                           something’s wrong. Our team of 20+ doctors love animals and speak                               their language – we know pets. You can count on us to be thorough,                              respect your time and budget, and only recommend what’s best for                                your pet. </p>
          </div>
</section>

<div id="wrapper">
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="squaredos"></div>
        <img src="images/vet.png" alt="vet">
</div>
</main>



<?php get_footer(); ?>


.wants img {
position: relative;
left: 80px; 
bottom: 50px;
height: 450px;
margin: 25px;
}

.wantstext {
font-size: 20px;
font-family: 'Sentinel', Georgia, serif;
position: relative;
bottom: 400px;
left: 430px;
margin: auto;
width: 40%;
}

#wrapper {
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
display: block;
line-height: 0;

}

#wrapper img {
display: block;
width: 200px;
}

.square {
height: 400px;
width: 400px;
background-color: hsl(166, 87%, 45%);
float: left;
}

.squaredos {
height: 400px;
width: 400px;
background-color: hsl(166, 50%, 45%);
float: right;
position: relative;
left: 50px;
}

#site-footer {
background: hsl(166, 87%, 45%);
width: 100%;
height: 110px;
margin-bottom: 0;
clear: both;
}

body, html {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Can you put the complete code on here?

Comment: Just did. Let me know if you anythihng else. And sorry for the awful formatting.

Comment: Without a **working** demo there's not much we can do. This will require the images also.